# Could not create the driver from NHibernate.Driver.MySqlDataDriver in Mono

Tags: fluent-nhibernate, mono

I have created an small application, in which I'm using Fluent Nhibernate. Application run fine on windows but give the exception in Mono.

```
    ---> NHibernate.HibernateException: Could not create the driver from
NHibernate.Driver.MySqlDataDriver, NHibernate, Version=3.1.0.4000,
Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=aa95f207798dfdb4. --->
System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown
by the target of an invocation. --->
System.Configuration.ConfigurationErrorsException: Failed to find or
load the registered .Net Framework Data Provider
'MySql.Data.MySqlClient'.
 at System.Data.Common.DbProviderFactories.GetFactory (System.String
providerInvariantName) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
```

I'm using Kubuntu 11.10 and Mono 2.10.5. Fluent NHibernate version is 1.2. Is Fluent NHibernate is not fully supported under Mono?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From my experience, Fluent NHibernate works fine on Mono.

I actually just got this working yesterday. Unfortunately, I don't have my code in front of me, but I'll give you some tips until I can post working code...

I assume you've downloaded the **MySql.Data.dll** and referenced it in your Mono project. Something to watch out for is that this file is usually called **MySQL.Data.dll** after download. It should be renamed to **MySql.Data.dll** (notice the case change on the '**Q**' and '**L**').

The library then has to be registered in the **GAC** to work with Mono. Simply placing the file in a relative path and referencing it doesn't work (I'm not completely sure why). More info is [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/connector-net-installation-unix.html).

```
gacutil /i MySql.Data.dll
```

If it still doesn't work, you may need to write a driver that descends from **NHibernate.Driver.ReflectionBasedDriver**. It's a very small piece of code that I'll post later when I can get to it.

Edit: Here's the MySQL driver I'm using.

```
public class MySqlDriver : NHibernate.Driver.ReflectionBasedDriver
{
    public MySqlDriver() : base(
        "MySql.Data, Version=6.4.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c5687fc88969c44d",
        "MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection, MySql.Data, Version=6.4.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c5687fc88969c44d",
        "MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand, MySql.Data, Version=6.4.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c5687fc88969c44d"
    ) { }

    public override bool UseNamedPrefixInParameter
    {
        get { return true; }
    }

    public override bool UseNamedPrefixInSql
    {
        get { return true; }
    }

    public override string NamedPrefix
    {
        get { return "@"; }
    }

    public override bool SupportsMultipleOpenReaders
    {
        get { return false; }
    }
}
```

...and the session factory functions

```
private string _ConnectionString = "";

private ISessionFactory CreateSessionFactory()
{
    return Fluently.Configure().Database(
        MySQLConfiguration.Standard.Driver<MySqlDriver>().ConnectionString(_ConnectionString)
    ).Mappings(
        m => m.FluentMappings.AddFromAssemblyOf<YourType>()
    ).ExposeConfiguration(
        BuildSchema
    ).BuildSessionFactory();
}

private void BuildSchema(Configuration config)
{
    //new SchemaExport(config).Create(false, true);
    new SchemaUpdate(config).Execute(false, true);
}
```

Comment: I tried installing it in GAC but it does not work. I'll try capitalizing name. This might be the reason as Linux is case sensitive.

Comment: Thanks buddy. It was the case sensitivity is the reason for issue. I changed the file name to MySql.Data.dll and it works. It also works if MySql.Data.dll is in the bin folder for application.

Comment: Thanks @Sharique, I went from `mysql.data.dll` via `Mysql.data.dll` and `Mysql.Data.dll` until your `MySql.Data.dll` finally worked.